# How to code quadruple loops in R? Or do it in Matrix way?

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to code methods in [this
paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0100014#s2)
in R. But I am stuck at their equation 7a and 7b.

Suppose we have a site by species matrix and a functional traits matrix
for species. We then can calculate distances between species.

```
library(FD)
data(dummy)
base = exp(1)
(dis = as.matrix(gowdis(dummy$trait)))

##        sp1    sp2    sp3    sp4    sp5    sp6    sp7    sp8
## sp1 0.0000 0.2182 0.5240 0.6737 0.5291 0.6100 0.4484 0.4073
## sp2 0.2182 0.0000 0.6678 0.5610 0.8146 0.5933 0.6863 0.2039
## sp3 0.5240 0.6678 0.0000 0.8226 0.4862 0.2785 0.4849 0.5959
## sp4 0.6737 0.5610 0.8226 0.0000 0.4843 0.7074 0.5575 0.2391
## sp5 0.5291 0.8146 0.4862 0.4843 0.0000 0.6067 0.3023 0.5586
## sp6 0.6100 0.5933 0.2785 0.7074 0.6067 0.0000 0.6188 0.4470
## sp7 0.4484 0.6863 0.4849 0.5575 0.3023 0.6188 0.0000 0.7030
## sp8 0.4073 0.2039 0.5959 0.2391 0.5586 0.4470 0.7030 0.0000

(comm = dummy$abun)

##       sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8
## com1    1   1   0   0   4   2   0   0
## com2    0   0   0   2   1   0   0   5
## com3    2   0   0   0   0   1   0   3
## com4    1   0   7   0   0   0   0   0
## com5    0   0   2   3   3   0   0   0
## com6    0   3   0   0   5   6   1   6
## com7    3   5   0   3   0   0   0   0
## com8    0   0   0   0   6   2   1   2
## com9    4   1   1   3   0   0   2   0
## com10   0   4   1   0   0   0   6   1
```

In this example, we have 10 sites and 8 species.

Here are the equations I want to code:

[image: equ7a]
<sub>(source: [plos.org](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/asset?id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0100014.e104.PNG))</sub>

[image: equ7b]
<sub>(source: [plos.org](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/asset?id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pone.0100014.e105.PNG))</sub>

`N` is the total number of sites (10 here); `Qz++2` is a constant;
`d_ij` is `dis[i,j]`; `z_ik` is the abundance of species i in site k
`dummy$comm[k,i]`; `q` is a positive number.

I think I can code them in loop. There must be a better way than a
loop to do this. Matrix manipulation?

My loop for q = 1:

```
N = nrow(comm)
S = ncol(comm)
comm_gamma = colSums(sweep(comm, 1, rowSums(comm, na.rm = TRUE), "/"))/N
comm_alpha = sweep(comm, 1, rowSums(comm, na.rm = TRUE), "/") 
dij = dis^2
Q_gamma = as.vector(comm_gamma %*% dij %*% matrix(comm_gamma, ncol = 1)) # Rao's Q for pooled assemblage.

FD_q_gamma = exp(-1 * sum(dij * 
                            (outer(comm_gamma, comm_gamma, FUN = "*")/Q_gamma) * 
                            log(outer(comm_gamma, comm_gamma, FUN = "*")/Q_gamma))) 
 # equa 6b in the paper.

# for q = 1
  vv = vector("list", length = N)
  for(k in 1:N){
    vv[[k]] = vector("list", length = N)
    for(m in 1:N){
      vv[[k]][[m]] = vector("list", length = S)
      for(i in 1:S){
        vv[[k]][[m]][[i]] = vector("list", length = S)
        for(j in 1:S){
          xx = log((comm_alpha[k,i] * comm_alpha[m,j]/(Q_gamma * N^2)), base)
          if(comm_alpha[k,i] == 0 | comm_alpha[m,j] == 0){
            xx = 0
          }
          vv[[k]][[m]][[i]][[j]] = (dij[i,j] * 
                                      (comm_alpha[k,i] * comm_alpha[m,j]/(Q_gamma * N^2) *
                                         xx
                                      ))
        }
      }
    }
  }

  (FD_q_alpha_loop  = exp(-1 * sum(unlist(vv), na.rm = T))/(N^2))

## [1] 2.336781

  # use outer()
  x = (outer(comm_alpha, comm_alpha, FUN = "*"))/(Q_gamma * (sum(comm_alpha)^2)) 
  x[x==0] = NA
  xx = x*log(x)
  for(k in 1:N){
    for(j in 1:S){
      xx[,,k,j] = sweep(xx[,,k,j], 2, dij[j,], "*")
    }
  }
  (FD_q_alpha_outer = exp(-1*sum(xx, na.rm=T))/N^2)

## [1] 2.336781

  FD_q_alpha_loop == FD_q_alpha_outer

## [1] TRUE

  (FD_q_beta = FD_q_gamma/FD_q_alpha_outer)

## [1] 6.966901

  # beta diversity should be between 1 and N^2 (100 here)
```

Does my code seems correct? (It seems ok)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to take a look at `?outer`

Comment: So what is the actual problem with the loops? Do you have code?

Comment: @bdecaf codes added.

Comment: what do mean the results seem wrong? do you mean your code looks strange or the numbers are not what you expected?

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum Results are not what I expect, too small.

Comment: just to make sure is Qz++2 the same as Q_gamma * sum(comm_gamma)^2 ?

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum yes. they are the same.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: The code looks good. I would suggest manually calculating a more simple example and then compare output and intermediate results to the program.